# PHP $_COOKIE parameter execution

Tags: php, cookies

I could not find the reason why my request fail for the following
My php code is:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
   echo '<p><h3><strong>Welcome '.$_COOKIE["param"].'</strong></h3></p>'; .....
```

When i request `exec('ls -al')` as param , the php code did not run the command.

On the response of the request it was like parameterized:

```
Welcome exec('ls -al')
```

What may the reason that failed this execution?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to, but putting php code to be evaulated in a cookie sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: I know its a bad idea but wonder why it fails..

Comment: @user2001965 Can you please accept the answer that you think is the most relevant? See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191928 if you are not sure how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$_COOKIE["param"]` is a string. You are echoing it. It is **not** supposed to run anything.

If you wanted to run a command in your PHP, you would have to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But as for running a command from a cookie value:

**DON'T DO IT!**

Comment: I do not agree with you , can you explain why the following works ? when it is tried manually ?? echo '<p><h3><strong>Welcome '.exec('ls -al).'</strong></h3></p>';

Comment: @user2001965 The difference in your comment is that you're directly calling the `shell_exec` function, whereas the value coming from the cookie is a *string*, not a function call. You can't run strings directly.

Comment: @user2001965 What you are actually doing is `echo '<p><h3><strong>Welcome '."exec('ls -al)".'</strong></h3></p>';`, notice the `"`. This WILL echo `exec('ls -al)`

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that the value of `$_COOKIE['param']` is `exec('ls -al')`, and you're expecting that to run when you `echo` it out?

That's not how it works. The value of that cookie will be the *string value* "exec('ls -al')", not the result of the executed code. If you think about it for a second, you'll understand why it would be a bad idea for a cookie to be able to auto-execute code.

It's not really a great idea to be running random commands through `exec()` anyway, *especially* if that input came from a user (which cookies do - the user can and will change them to try to attack you).

Instead, you should be using other input that your code can interpret as a signal to run certain code. For example, you could have the `param` value hold the string `list files`, and your code would see that value and run `exec('ls -al')` for you.

You *still* shouldn't be `exec`ing code to do this though, since it's very easy to accidentally run dangerous commands that way. Instead, you should use PHP's built-in functions as much as possible, and only after sanitizing your inputs and only running known values.

For your case, PHP has [a bunch of functions](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.file.php) that let you interact with the filesystem of your server. Use those to get a list of files on the system instead.

Comment: I do not agree with you , can you explain why the following works ? when it is tried manually ?? echo '<p><h3><strong>Welcome '.exec('ls -al).'</strong></h3></p>';

Comment: @user2001965 I explained it in response to your same comment on Mathieu Imbert's answer.